# How To Remove Light Effect UWP Community Toolkit?

Tags: uwp, windows-community-toolkit

Here I run a Light animation on a selected ListView item when it is selected:

```
var element = (FrameworkElement)listView.ItemsPanelRoot.Children[listView.SelectedIndex];
await element.Light(20, 500).StartAsync();
```

Now how do I get rid of the Light effect brush after the animation is complete?

I tried getting the child visual and running SpriteVisual.Brush.Dispose() and SpriteVisual.Dispose() neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

when you apply the animation of **Light** you are actually filling the element with Light to a specific distance ( the first parameter of your Light(20,500) method ). So after you the animation is complete the element has a light of 20 in your case. Now to bring it back to normal you just need to set its **light back to 0** in whatever time you prefer ( the second parameter is duration of the animation. ) So after running first animation you need to run a second animation to bring it back to 0.

```
var element = (FrameworkElement)listView.ItemsPanelRoot.Children[listView.SelectedIndex];
await element.Light(20, 500).StartAsync();
await element.Light(0, 500).StartAsync();
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that first actually.  With Distance at 0 the spotlight disappears but shadow aspect of the effect stays in place so the UIElement is completely darkened.

Comment: in that case consider opening a github issue on windows community toolkit repo :)